# How to initialize local variables under specific name_scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
with tf.name_scope('trans_part'):
    with tf.name_scope('t_conv3'):    
        # next line is the error line
        t = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(t, filters=f, kernel_size=w, strides=s, padding='same')
        t = tf.nn.tanh(t)

    with tf.name_scope('identical_conv4'):
        t = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=t, filters=f, kernel_size=w, strides=1, padding='same')
        t  = tf.nn.tanh(t)

        t = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=t, filters=f, kernel_size=w, strides=1, padding='same')
        t = tf.nn.tanh(t)
```

## Initlialize

```
var = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='trans_part')

sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=var))
```

## Error:

```
line 43 
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_transpose/kernel_1
```

## Question:

1. how to initialize the variables under specific name_scope?
2. Is this caused by initializer or name_scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.variable_scope()` instead of `tf.name_scope()`. `tf.name_scope()` will append scope name only to the resulting tensor name (e.g. to the result of applying convolutional/dense layer) but not to the underlying variables. `tf.variable_scope()`, however, will append the scope name to both.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 3))
t = x
with tf.variable_scope('trans_part'):
    with tf.name_scope('t_conv3', default_name=scope):    
        t = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(t,
                                       filters=3,
                                       kernel_size=3,
                                       strides=1,
                                       padding='same')
        print(t.name) # trans_part/t_conv3/conv2d_transpose/BiasAdd:0
        t = tf.nn.tanh(t)
    with tf.name_scope('identical_conv4'):
        t = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=t,
                             filters=3,
                             kernel_size=3,
                             strides=1,
                             padding='same')
        t  = tf.nn.tanh(t)

        t = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=t,
                             filters=3,
                             kernel_size=3,
                             strides=1,
                             padding='same')
        t = tf.nn.tanh(t)

var_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='trans_part')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=var_list))

print([v.name for v in var_list])
# ['trans_part/conv2d_transpose/kernel:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d_transpose/bias:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d/kernel:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d/bias:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d_1/kernel:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d_1/bias:0']
```

You can also add the name of the scope to the names of layers you define and then filter out those variables that do not have scope name substring in their names:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 3))
t = x
with tf.name_scope('trans_part') as scope:
    with tf.name_scope('t_conv3'):    
        # next line is the error line
        t = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(t,
                                       filters=3,
                                       kernel_size=3,
                                       strides=1,
                                       padding='same',
                                       name=scope + 'con2d_transpose')
        t = tf.nn.tanh(t)

    with tf.name_scope('identical_conv4') as scope2:
        t = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=t,
                             filters=3,
                             kernel_size=3,
                             strides=1,
                             padding='same',
                             name=scope + 'conv2d1')
        t  = tf.nn.tanh(t)

        t = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=t,
                             filters=3,
                             kernel_size=3,
                             strides=1,
                             padding='same',
                             name=scope + 'conv2d2')
        t = tf.nn.tanh(t)

# from all trainable variables pick those that do have 'trans_part`
# substring in their name        
var_list = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if 'trans_part' in v.name]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=var_list))

print([v.name for v in var_list])
# ['trans_part/con2d_transpose/kernel:0',
#  'trans_part/con2d_transpose/bias:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d1/kernel:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d1/bias:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d2/kernel:0',
#  'trans_part/conv2d2/bias:0']
```

Note that in this case the names should be unique for each layer you define!